# Custom TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a TextView like below.
I don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Search for __How to create a tooltip drawable__

Comment: check this https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout

Answer (score 1):

I feel that you would prefer a simple answer, instead of the most-elegant answer.

You should consider the bubble point as bubble body as two things. Prepare a drawable that looks like the bubble point, and then do something like the following:

**my_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tooltip_pointer_up"
        android:tint="#f0f0f0"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#f0f0f0"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Your manager gives constructive and valuable feedback"
            android:textColor="@color/darkForeground"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you. I am fine with both drawables or this way. But in drawable the arrow is not appearing after setting the background. And in your way the arrow image is not connected to the textbox.

Comment: The drawable 'ic_tooltip_pointer_up' is only in my computer. You will have to make your own and replace here. You can use Figma for things like that.
As for your second concern, I quickly spun this up. You can use drawable for the bubble part as well. Arrow and bubble will then easily look connected. For the bubble drawable, i suggest you take a look at how to create 9-patch images.